# How enable xdebug only for one host in Nginx

Tags: nginx, xdebug

How i can enable xdebug only for one `virtualserver` in Nginx?

In Apache i can config that via .htaccess("`php_value xdebug.remote_enable On`"), for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution in [Is it possible to set up PHP-FPM with different pool-options (xdebug enabled / xdebug disabled)](https://serverfault.com/questions/481960/is-it-possible-to-set-up-php-fpm-with-different-pool-options-xdebug-enabled-x)

I create second PHP-FPM pool with
`php_admin_flag[xdebug.remote_enable]=on` in config and different socket path of course.

In Nginx host config location section, i can choose socket with or without xdebug for `location{...}`