# How can I create separate configuration files for php (cli) and php-fpm on an arch linux

Tags: php, php-fpm, php.ini, arch-linux

Is it possible to create separate php.ini files for php (cli) and php-fpm, like it is possible on debian and ubuntu with two folders `/etc/php/7.0/cli` and `/etc/php/7.0/fpm`?

I will be also cool if I can load independent modules with a `conf.d` directory for each subsystem.

Has anyone an idea how can I configure it separately?

I also tried to use the structure like it is configured in ubuntu 16.04 without success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found a few tweaks to solve my problem.

**First**: load a separate `php.ini` files:

A user in a arch linux forum posted this from the `man php` page:

```
FILES
   php-cli.ini    The configuration file for the CLI version of PHP.

   php.ini        The standard configuration file will only be used when php-cli.ini cannot be found.
```

If I creating a `/etc/php/php-cli.ini` file only this file will be loaded and not `/etc/php/php.ini` with the `php` cli command. `php-fpm` is still loading the `/etc/php/php.ini`.

**Second**: load different module configurations:

I have found in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file.scan) the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` environment variable.
Therefore I have moved the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service` file to `/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service` and added the following configuration to the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
Environment="PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php/fpm/conf.d" ; <-- I have added this line
PIDFile=/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/php-fpm.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After restarting/reloading the services, php-fpm loads only the files from `/etc/php/fpm/conf.d` and no longer from `/etc/php/conf.d`. This allows me to configure cli and fpm separately.

Perhaps this is not the best solution but I fits to my usecase. If everyone have a better solution, don't hesitate to post your answer!

Comment: This second approach is extremely useful for debugging, i.e. you create suffixed copies of the php-fpm service and conf files/dirs, specify a separate fpm config as you have, optionally specify a different ini with `--php-ini`, then load the xdebug only in the second service. Of course, the second service needs to run on a different port/socket. I set `Environment="PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php-debugger.d:"` in my service file, the colon added so it loads all the default modules in addition to the xdebug one I copied to the `debugger.d` dir.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do this for the cli version:

```
php -c /path/to/your/php.ini
```

and leave the defaults with the ones served over php-fpm. Or even better, add this to your login scripts

```
# ~/.bashrc
# aliases and personal functions

# PHP source personal ini
alias php='php -c /path/to/your/php.ini'

# colorize ls
alias ls='ls --color'
...
```

It would have been better if you had stated which version(s) you are using

Comment: nice idea, but not exactly what I'm looking for. Perhaps if there no other way. Thanks.

Comment: well, maybe there is, please do share what version of php, php-fpm and your basic setup (are you using nginx, apache etc). How you have setup php-fpm. maybe from there, we can be helpful